# Should I talk to my advisor on this?

Tags: phd, colleagues

I really need some advice on this.
I don't trust the other PhD student in our group at all.
Reasons; The first week I came, he bothered me with his questions 'What is your religion?, When I will go?, etc.'. he did not ask something scientific.
And with the other student they spoke in their own language whenever there was just the three of us.
I felt excluded and did not built any friendship.
Yes, I know it's not a big problem, but since I didn't act close to this person, I look unfriendly at the moment.
Should I talk with my advisor? or Should I talk while there is this Phd student with us?

Thank you.

edit:
Thank you and I am sorry for shortcomings. I don't want to go into too much detail, in fact, I just want to take comments on what I wrote.
We are only 2 doctoral and 1 postdoctoral students (because of covid restrictions they couldn't take a new students). Now, I have no problem with my group, also with other postdoc but I am really tired of this PhD student. We just use the same lab.
If I go into detail, I have a lot to write, so I do not want to write. For example, I want something from the other people or from our advisor, the next day she comes and takes the everything.
she does silly things and asks silly questions towards me, but she is very good to the advisor. I am just saying 'yes, ok, no problem' to her.
I want to talk with my advisor, but I don't want to be trouble maker.
Common language is English, our group is international.
I submit my papers, so I going well.

Comment: I suspect we need more details, particularly since you reported similar problems [six months ago](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166719/i-feel-left-out-from-the-group). How far into the program are you? Is the problem only with one student, or with the whole group? How closely do you work with this student? Is there any problem that affects your research, or just a lack of friendliness? You report concern about a language barrier; are they speaking the local language, or is it just a coincidence that they all speak some other language that you do not speak?

Comment: where in the world? it looks like there is some cultural differences, on top of peculiar individual characters.

Comment: As far you are going well, I do not see anything dramatic and inherent to Academia. Of course, it would be better to work in a nice environment but nothing is perfect. You may said something in future, if the supervisor ask for a strict collaboration between you and that student. It seems to me a general problem of interpersonal relations, so it is hard to say something.